# Create an App Engine Project ID command line

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to create an app engine ID through command line. Right now our tool (http://deploy.plus.io) allows you to upload our template to your app engine, but the user still has to go through Google.

Our ideal workflow would be:

User Signs In (Google OAuth) > Deploy Instance > Code gets uploaded in background > Sees Secret Key & App Spot Project URL + Gets Emailed (Secret Key * App Spot Project URL)

We want this to happen within 2 clicks. (Login and Deploy)

Is it possible to create app engine instances via an API similar to how AWS is setup?

EDIT: If anyone is looking at this trying to solve the same problem I was you can use the command line tools for App Engine and authenticate a user using their request token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for user to own their own GAE account they need to have Gmail/GoogleApps account and create a new GAE application themselves. Afaik, you can not create that in their name.

OTOH, they can deploy (your) code to their GAE app, via your web application, by giving your app admin privileges via OAuth. Much like [Codenvy](https://codenvy.com) does.

Comment: Hi Peter,

If they have the GAE account is there an API I can tap into that will do deployments?

Comment: This can be done - Codenvy does it. But it's not really documented, so you'll have to do some reverse engineering.